# How to delete a column from a table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, ddl, alter-table

Given the table created using:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_Country
(
  CountryId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  IsDeleted bit,
  PRIMARY KEY (CountryId) 
)
```

How can I delete the column `IsDeleted`?

Answer (score 806):

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_Country DROP COLUMN IsDeleted;
```

[Here's](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21bdf) a working example.

Note that the `COLUMN` keyword is optional, as MySQL will accept just `DROP IsDeleted`. Also, to drop multiple columns, you have to separate them by commas and include the `DROP` for each one.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_Country
  DROP COLUMN IsDeleted,
  DROP COLUMN CountryName;
```

This allows you to `DROP`, `ADD` and `ALTER` multiple columns on the same table in the one statement. From the [MySQL reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html):

> You can issue multiple `ADD`, `ALTER`, `DROP`, and `CHANGE` clauses in a single `ALTER TABLE` statement, separated by commas. This is a MySQL extension to standard SQL, which permits only one of each clause per `ALTER TABLE` statement.

Answer (score 100):

Use [`ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) with `DROP COLUMN` to drop a column from a table, and `CHANGE` or `MODIFY` to change a column.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_Country DROP COLUMN IsDeleted;
ALTER TABLE tbl_Country MODIFY IsDeleted tinyint(1) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE tbl_Country CHANGE IsDeleted IsDeleted tinyint(1) NOT NULL;
```

Comment: You can use Change or Modify column to do the same. Check the link which will give you the idea of updating a column using ALTER TABLE

Answer (score 43):

To delete a single column:

```
ALTER TABLE `table1` DROP `column1`;
```

To delete multiple columns:

```
ALTER TABLE `table1`
DROP `column1`,
DROP `column2`,
DROP `column3`;
```

Comment: It also works for columns with `reserved words`, like `order`

Answer (score 16):

You can use

```
alter table <tblname> drop column <colname>
```

Answer (score 15):

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` DROP `columnname`;
```

Or,

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` DROP COLUMN `columnname`;
```

Answer (score 13):

If you are running MySQL 5.6 onwards, you can make this operation online, allowing other sessions to read and write to your table while the operation is been performed:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_Country DROP COLUMN IsDeleted, ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE;
```

Answer (score 10):

Use `ALTER`:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `tbl_Country` DROP COLUMN `column_name`;
```

Answer (score 8):

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_Country DROP columnName;
```

Answer (score 3):

It is worth mentioning that MySQL 8.0.23 and above supports [Invisible Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/invisible-columns.html#invisible-column-metadata)

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_Country(
  CountryId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  IsDeleted bit,
  PRIMARY KEY (CountryId) 
);

INSERT INTO tbl_Country VALUES (1, 1), (2,0);

ALTER TABLE tbl_Country ALTER COLUMN IsDeleted SET INVISIBLE;

SELECT * FROM tbl_Country;
CountryId
1
2

ALTER TABLE tbl_Country DROP COLUMN IsDeleted;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1560f65244f019e5de550091d8d3d183)**

It may be useful in scenarios when there is need to "hide" a column for a time being before it could be safely dropped(like reworking corresponding application/reports etc.).

Answer (score -1):

**Adding column :**

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
ADD (Columnname_1  datatype,

Columnname_2  datatype, …Columnname_n  datatype);
```

**Dropping column :**

```
ALTER TABLE table_name

DROP COLUMN column_name;
```

**Modifying Column :**

```
ALTER TABLE table_name

MODIFY column_name column_type;
```

**Rename column :**

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
RENAME TO new_table_name ;
```