# reset mysql table column every day, week, month

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

I want to reset my mysql table column every day (12 AM), week and month. I have just single row in my mysql table.

```
$current_date = date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$current_date = date('H:i:s');
$timestamp = strtotime($current_date);
$gettime = date("h:i A", $timestamp);
if($gettime == "11:59 PM")
{
    update mysql table column to 0 ???          
}
```

I have tried this above code for reset table column every day. But, I'm not sure. Is this the right way to reset column? If it is correct then How do I do this for week and month?

Comment: See this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/13968494/ and use cron.

Comment: Wow that's an incredibly long piece of code to get current time. And that logic will need to run conitnously always which is wrong. This is the job of cron scheduler that runs at the specific time and updates your table.

Comment: You should use cron job to update table values

Answer (score 0):

What about use crontab?

Make a shell script with mysql command line tool.