# A previous used property always shown up in RequestBody example(SwaggerUI) and ResponseBody(json)

Tags: java, mysql, json, spring, rest

I am writing a Spring boot application linked to MySQL, in one of my packages:

> com.Employee.DataManagement.salaries

[image]

I misspelled a property's name:

```
@Column(name = "from_date")
java.sql.Date fromeDate
```

As you can see, there is an extra "e" in the name. But I didn't realize it at that time and run the main java file(the one with annotation @SpringBootApplication) for a few times. Then I removed the extra "e" and the property becomes this:

```
@Column(name = "from_date")
java.sql.Date fromDate
```

Setter and Getter looks like this:

```
public Date getFromeDate() {
    return fromDate;
}

public void setFromeDate(Date fromDate) {
    this.fromDate = fromDate;
}
```

However, when I run the java file again, the old property name won't go away. The are some screenshot:

When I use GET and get the response, the from date in JSON always display as the previous name.
[image]

When I want to POST new data into the database, the example given by Swagger is like this:
[image]

But in the RequestBody I can ignore the misspell property and only use the correct one, write like this:

`{
  "embeddedKeyId": {
    "employee": {
      "emp_no": 123123
    },
    "fromDate": "2012-10-27",
  },
  "salary": 450,
  "toDate": "2333-08-09"
}`

But the output will still display as the old property name.

I searched through the project to see if I forgot to change some property name, but I got nothing.

Lastly, here is the screenshot of the salaries table in database
[image]

Comment: How you  getters / setters look like? And why dont you simply remove misspelled column from db https://stackoverflow.com/a/13968514/1032167 or even wipe your db and let hibernate to recreate it?

Comment: I use the @Column("from_date") so in the database, the mapped column name is always "from_date"

Comment: fix your getters names `getFromeDate => getFromDate` and setter `setFromeDate => setFromDate`

Comment: By default Spring uses Jackson to work with json and Jackson by default will use getters and setters and not field names so json field names come from `getters name -> field name` conversion with rules based on JavaBeans Specification. You could use `@JsonProperty("somename")` to override this behavior, but it is not needed in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is cited from [varren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1032167/varren)'s answer

Change setter and getter from:

```
public Date getFromeDate() {
  return fromDate;
}

public void setFromeDate(Date fromDate) {
  this.fromDate = fromDate;
}
```

To:

```
public Date getFromDate() {
  return fromDate;
}

public void setFromDate(Date fromDate) {
  this.fromDate = fromDate;
}
```

Without "e".