# Key column '' doesn't exist in table while the column exists

Tags: mysql

i have a simple and weird problem .
when i run

```
 alter table verizon_device_usages drop verizon_device_id
```

mysql gives this error .

```
alter table verizon_device_usages drop verizon_device_id
> 1072 - Key column 'verizon_device_id' doesn't exist in table
> Time: 0.003s
```

but when i run

```
 alter table verizon_device_usages ADD COLUMN verizon_device_id VARCHAR(15)
```

my sql returns this error :

```
alter table verizon_device_usages ADD COLUMN verizon_device_id VARCHAR(15)
> 1060 - Duplicate column name 'verizon_device_id'
> Time: 0.02s
```

i just want to remove that column with laravel migration or even query but i cant . any idea why its like that ?? i can see the column on table exists

Comment: Could you please provide DDL (create table....) for your table?

Comment: @asd-tm i am using the laravel migration to make that table

Comment: $table->unsignedBigInteger('verizon_device_id')->index();

Comment: i can even rename that column without problem or make it nullable , but i cant drop it

Comment: Is it possible you need to say `... DROP COLUMN column_name`, including the word `COLUMN`?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you've simply lost `column` in your script:

```
alter table verizon_device_usages drop column verizon_device_id;
```

[see also here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13968494/5043424)

However the official documentation says:

> The word COLUMN is optional and can be omitted, except for RENAME
> COLUMN (to distinguish a column-renaming operation from the RENAME
> table-renaming operation).